# WordPress, disabling parts of Roots theme (like Bootstrap)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a WordPress site. The Roots theme was installed by someone else. I want to code pages as directly as possible without using Bootstrap. I don't completely understand WordPress, but it looks to me like `base.php` is code that wraps every page. I'm wondering how much of this I can change without messing up the theme. Mainly I don't want to use Bootstrap. Can I just remove the references to the 'container' and 'row' classes? By the way, what are the 'wrap' and 'content' and 'main' classes? How do I find out what roots_main_class() is? Is there another way to do this, like not loading bootstrap.css?

```
<?php get_template_part('templates/head'); ?>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

  <!--[if lt IE 7]><div class="alert"><?php _e('You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.', 'roots'); ?></div><![endif]-->

  <?php
    do_action('get_header');
    // Use Bootstrap's navbar if enabled in config.php
    if (current_theme_supports('bootstrap-top-navbar')) {
      get_template_part('templates/header-top-navbar');
    } else {
      get_template_part('templates/header');
    }
  ?>

  <div class="wrap container" role="document">
    <div class="content row">
      <div class="main <?php echo roots_main_class(); ?>" role="main">
        <?php include roots_template_path(); ?>
      </div><!-- /.main -->
      <?php if (roots_display_sidebar()) : ?>
      <aside class="sidebar <?php echo roots_sidebar_class(); ?>" role="complementary">
        <?php include roots_sidebar_path(); ?>
      </aside><!-- /.sidebar -->
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- /.content -->
  </div><!-- /.wrap -->

  <?php get_template_part('templates/footer'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is trying to cover a lot of different points. A couple of observations:

1. If you don't completely understand Wordpress then I would strongly recommend you familiarise yourself with the WP documentation first.
2. Bootstrap is a framework; why don't you just build on top of it and use it as a starting point?
3. If you *really* don't want to use Bootstrap then it would be a lot simpler to switch to a different theme
4. Looking at the roots theme, there isn't bootstrap.css; there's main.min.css. You can either: A) edit that directly, B) prevent it from loading by commenting out line 14 of `lib/scripts.php` and enqueuing your own CSS or C) leave it as is and load your own CSS as an additional stylesheet by enqueuing it in 'lib/scripts.php`. To understand how to enqueue stylesheets in WP, refer to the [WP Codex entry for wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style).

I'd strongly consider rethinking your question so that it is easier to answer, and maybe posting it as separate questions rather than one multi-faceted question.

Comment: You are right, I'm pretty confused and grasping at any information I can get. Thanks for taking the time to answer and not just down-voting my question. The reason I don't want to use Bootstrap is that I'm focusing on certain aspects of composing the look of my site, especially getting edges to align, and I've been fighting Bootstrap and Roots. One of the big purposes of Bootstrap is to make a site responsive to the screen width and mobile-ready, and that is not a high priority for me right now. I think I'll switch themes. I'm looking at WP Framework, considered a "blank" theme.

Comment: Another starter themes you might want to look is (Bones.)[http://themble.com/bones/] I've used it on a number of projects; it's not a 'blank' theme as there is some styling, but it's light-weight and easy to remove or adapt. I like it because all the files are pretty well documented. There's also a [3-part guide WP-tuts guide on using Bones as a starting point.](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/making-a-theme-with-bones-getting-started/) Good luck!